# Cannot find CEL ethereum token

Tags: cryptography

I am trying to get information aobut the Celsius token (CEL, https://etherscan.io/token/0xaaaebe6fe48e54f431b0c390cfaf0b017d09d42d) in Mathematica.

However, it seems like it is not working. These return error (CEL is not found):

```
BlockchainTokenData["CEL", 
  BlockchainBase -> {"Ethereum", "Mainnet"}] // Dataset
BlockchainTokenData["Celsius", 
  BlockchainBase -> {"Ethereum", "Mainnet"}] // Dataset
```

Also if I look at the sorted list of Names or Symbols returned by this, I cannot find CEL token:

```
erc20Tokens = 
  BlockchainTokenData["ERC20", 
   BlockchainBase -> {"Ethereum", "Mainnet"}];
```

Any idea why?